# When Radio button checked, datetime picker does not show and checked false doesnt work

Tags: jquery, radio-button, checked

I have two radio button, Deliver Now and Delivery at. Deliver Now is default checked. If the customer wants at later delivery when he clicks the delivery at button, the date picker must be shown and Delivery Now radio button must be unchecked. But these dont happen. The date picker is not shown and Delivery Now radio doesnt turn to unchecked. What is the wrong with my code? Can Anyone help. Thanks.

Below you can see my view;

```
<div class="checkout-nameoncake-itemcontainer">
    <div class="checkout-nameoncake-name">
        <label class="label-checkout-deliverytime">Deliver Now(~ 45dk.)</label><input type="radio" id="DeliveryNowRadio" checked="checked" name="DeliveryNow" value=" " />
        <label class="label-checkout-deliverytime">Delivert at </label><input type="radio" id="DeliveryLaterRadio" name="RequestedDeliveryDate" value=" " />
    </div>
    <div class="checkout-nameoncake-details">
        <input type="date" name="name" class="datepicker" id="datepicker" style="margin: 17% 0 0 5%;border-radius: 7%;border: solid;border-width: thin;border-color: lightblue;display:none" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Below you can see my jquery.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DeliveryLaterRadio").click(function () {
            $("#DeliveryNowRadio").prop("checked", false);
            $(".datepicker").css("display", "inline-block");
        });

        $("#DeliveryNowRadio").click(function () {
            $("#DeliveryLaterRadio").prop("checked", false);
            $(".datepicker").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code out on plunker, and it works:

https://plnkr.co/OJVF85JgJiZSghMtyUtf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="checkout-nameoncake-itemcontainer">
      <div class="checkout-nameoncake-name">
        <label class="label-checkout-deliverytime">Deliver Now(~ 45dk.)</label>
        <input type="radio" id="DeliveryNowRadio" checked="checked" name="DeliveryNow" value=" " />
        <label class="label-checkout-deliverytime">Delivert at </label>
        <input type="radio" id="DeliveryLaterRadio" name="RequestedDeliveryDate" value=" " />
      </div>
      <div class="checkout-nameoncake-details">
        <input type="date" name="name" class="datepicker" id="datepicker" style="margin: 17% 0 0 5%;border-radius: 7%;border: solid;border-width: thin;border-color: lightblue;display:none" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DeliveryLaterRadio").click(function () {
            $("#DeliveryNowRadio").prop("checked", false);
            $(".datepicker").css("display", "inline-block");
        });

        $("#DeliveryNowRadio").click(function () {
            $("#DeliveryLaterRadio").prop("checked", false);
            $(".datepicker").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
  </script>
  </body>



</html>
```

Comment: I didnt undertstand what happend but it now works for me too. Thanks for your time.@raszpi

Comment: great, glad to help :]